# Is it possible to determine a final orientation from an initial angular velocity and constant angular acceleration analytically?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotation, complex-numbers, angular-velocity, analyticity

I am looking to model the rotation of a ball over time. I have the following information:

- an initial orientation, as a quaternion
- an initial angular velocity, as X/Y/Z components, fixed to the global frame
- a constant angular acceleration, as X/Y/Z components, fixed to the global frame

I am aware of various methods to do this numerically (i.e., adding instantaneous angular velocity at a small fixed time step), but I am wondering if it is possible to derive a function that solves the orientation after $t$ seconds analytically?

**Edit:** it is important to note the initial angular velocity and the angular acceleration are not necessarily around the same axis, so it cannot be solved with $\omega_0 t+(\alpha /2) t^2$

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)

Comment: I doubt there's an analytic solution. I think the [Dyson series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series) is relevant: it tells you how to compose time-varying infinitesimal transformations. That is, you have the IVP $R'(t)=\frac{v_0+at}2R(t),R(0)=1,$ where $R(t)$ is the rotation of the ball from $t=0$ to time $t,$ $v$ is the angular velocity (in purely imaginary generator form), and $a$ is the angular acceleration. The solution is $R(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{-n}\int_{0\le t_0\le\cdots\le t_{n-1}\le t}(v_0+at_0)\ldots(v_0+at)\,dt_0\ldots dt.$